# DNS question, need to create a dns for home WK2008R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I'm stucked at very simple and stupid situation. Let me describe the situation - at home i have a Windows Server 2008 R2 computer, which is used with Hyper-V technology, where another PDC Server 2008, Exchange and other testing virtual machines are running. I've bought a domain name http://bit.ly/dbNJjQ, with possibility to manage domain records. The main question is how to configure DNS server on PC server station with possibility to work with domain name both locally and globally.

The LAN configuration is following:

Dedicated ip address, linking to DI-524 Router, where DMZ zone set for IP of PC server station. This will result, that all requests, from internet will lead to Server station PC.

Really don't have any ideas :( help me brothers and sisters !

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

<disclaimer> If you're doing this to learn how DNS works, then I say "right on", but if you have any intention of using these services for anything beyond just learning how it works, I can't stress strongly enough that having a single DNS hosted in the same location as your web servers is a **bad** move.

There are plenty of commercial DNS providers (some free, most not) that will take care of all of this for you, take the worry of hosting your own DNS off your shoulders and may even offer you a [100% SLA](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/) at very reasonable prices.</disclaimer>

Comment: Agreed! Setting up split-DNS services on the same system as your web server can be a bit of a headache and single point of failure. If you're interested in a free DNS service, I'd suggest ZoneEdit.  They've been very reliable for me... ZE isn't appropriate for business infrastructures but for home networks it should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i'll have a mind.

What's the main problem point for this situation - router ?

Comment: @VoVA - the main problem is all the single points of failure. One internet connection, one router, one switch, one server. A single point of failure for something as critical as DNS (which is more critical than the web server) is dangerous

Comment: @Farseeker, as i said - it's possible to hold NS records on NIC service provider. NS records is very critical for DNS, right ?

PS Can you offer some DNS education lessons ? :)

Comment: @VoVA, these records that your registrar holds are called `glue` records, so that the dns knows how to contact the nameserver if the two are the same. Usually though you can specify an IP address for NS, which can make life easier. As for DNS lessons, the only thing I can suggest is 1) Read around on serverfault. There's a lot on here for DNS already (http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/DNS), and 2) Just try and do it yourself, and remember that sites like serverfault.com exist for when you get stuck.

Comment: The first step though is to choose which DNS service you want to run. Seeing as you have your hand on a Windows Server box, there's no reason you can't run your Windows Server box as your DNS using the built-in DNS service. You'll just need to open up your firewall and port forwardings to enable the service to be queried from outside your network.